# azure WCF and mutual certificate auth - how?

Tags: wcf, azure

I have got quite a long way with this. I want a WCF service hosted in azure that uses client certificate authentication.

Everything works with the client cert requirement turned off and server cert on; ie

```
   <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
```

but when I change to

```
   <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
```

I get

```
The SSL settings for the service 'SslRequireCert' does not match those of the IIS 'None'.
```

This seems to suggest that I need to change my IIS configuration. But I am running inside azure emulator, not IIS.

I tried adding

```
 <system.webServer>
      <security>
         <access sslFlags="ssl">
      </security>
   </system.webServer>
```

but the web server did not like that at all; says this is a locked configuration option

All help gratefully received

answer: unlock the iis config file with appcmd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unlock the iis config file with appcmd